# Is there a way to reverse the comparison direction of ruby case statements?

Tags: ruby, set, switch-statement

Let me explain with code, and perhaps it will become more clear what I'm asking. This of course is hypothetical code given that it does not currently function in the manner I'm intending (the deductive and creative abilities of humans I'm clearly leveraging here).

```
class AnySet < Array
  def ===(other)
    (other & self).any?
  end
end

class AllSet < Array
  def ===(other)
    other.sort == self.sort
  end
end

case AnySet.new([:bar])
when [:bar]
  true # a more complex...
when [:bar, :biz]
  true # result could...
when [:biz]
  false # be imagined.
end

case AllSet.new([:biz, :bar])
when [:bar, :biz]
  true # a more complex...
when [:biz, :foo]
  false # result could...
when [:biz]
  false # be imagined.
end
```

Note: poor `:biz`. :)

Wouldn't this be handy? Anyway to accomplish this or am I restricted to building my `A**Set`s in the `when` clauses?

Edit: I tweaked the `A**Set` classes to extend `Array`. Not really important, I'm just OCD.

Comment: Your (hypothetical) code alone does not make clear what behavior you're looking for. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

With ruby's built-in case/when it's not possible. `when` clauses will contain receivers of the threequals operator and its argument will be the value you passed to the `case`.

You could flex your metaprogramming muscles and cook up a custom function/DSL for this.

```
consider AllSet.new([:biz, :bar]) do
  if_matches [:bar, :biz]  { 'first' }
  if_matches [:biz, :foo]  { 'second' }
  if_matches [:biz] { 'third' }
end
```

It's up to you to decide if this is an improvement in readability/maintainability (or whichever other metric is important to you).